# Why $G/F(G)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of ${\rm Out}(F(G))$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, automorphism-groups, normal-subgroups

I know two facts and I’ve managed to figure out how to prove one, but the other one is still a little confusing.

> Let $G$ be a finite solvable group and $F(G)$ is the Fitting subgroup of $G$.
>
> (1) $G/Z(F(G))$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(F(G))$;
>
> (2) $G/F(G)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of ${\rm Out}(F(G))$.

Proof of (1):

$F(G)$ is normal in $G$, so $G=N_G(F(G))$. Since $G$ is solvable, $Z(F(G))=C_G(F(G))$. $F(G)$ is a characteristic subgroup of $G$ and $Z(F(G))$ is a characteristic subgroup of $F(G)$, therefore $Z(F(G))$ is characteristic and normal in $G$, and $G/Z(F(G))$ is hence well-defined. By the $N/C$ theorem, $G/Z(F(G))=N_G(F(G))/C_G(F(G))$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(F(G))$.

About (2), I asked a question and have got some ideas.

I know that $F(G)/Z(F(G))\cong {\rm Inn}(F(G))$ and by (1) that $G/Z(F(G))$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of {\rm Aut}(F(G))$.

So by the third isomorphism theorem, we have $G/F(G) \cong G/Z(F(G)) \big/ F(G)/Z(F(G))$.

**If it is true that, say, “if $A\cong M$ and $B\cong N$ where $B\trianglelefteq A$ and $N\trianglelefteq M$ then $A/B\cong M/N$”, then we’re done. However, it is not true in general.  I believe that I ignored something important. So what should I do next? It really seems very close. It’s quite obvious to think in an intuitive way that $G/F(G)\cong G/Z(F(G)\big/ F(G)/Z(F(G))$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(G)/{\rm Inn}(G)$ since the $G/Z(F(G))$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(G)$ and $F(G)/Z(F(G))\cong {\rm Inn}(G)$. But it’s not sufficient in a proof. I think there’s still something missing.**

**Let me just make my question clear.** I want to take an example. Assume that $A$ is a subgroup of $C$ and $B\trianglelefteq A$. Also, assume that $N\trianglelefteq M$. If $A\cong M$ and $B\cong N$, then it is Not true in general that $A/B\cong M/N$. So in the case that we were talking about, $C={\rm Aut}(F(G))$, $B={\rm Inn}(F(G))$, $M=G/Z(F(G))$, $N=F/Z(F(G))$, it’s just the same: $M$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $C$, namely $A$, and $N\cong B$. But we don’t have $A/B\cong M/N$ in general. I want to know how to prove it in this specific case.

Any help is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Often *"X is isomorphic a subgroup of Y"* is poor way of starting *"this natural map from X to Y is an isomorphism"*, which in case is not easy to state can better be stated as *"there is a natural injective homomorphism from X to Y"*. By poor way, I mean that when one applies such a statement, one needs to refer to some given natural map, not the bare existence of such a map.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Thanks. I mentioned that in my post, this isomorphism theorem does play a key role in the proof. But I got stuck after using this theorem.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson $F(G)/Z(F(G))\cong {\rm Inn}(F(G))$ and by (1) that $G/Z(F(G))\cong {\rm Aut}(F(G))$. If it is true that, say, “if $A\cong M$ and $B\cong N$ where $B\trianglelefteq A$ and $N\trianglelefteq M$ then $A/B\cong M/N$”, then we’re done. However, it is not true in general. It’s exactly where I got stuck. The isomorphism theorem does bring me very close to the conclusion. But there’s still something in my way.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Thanks. You mean $G/F(Z(G))$ is isomorphic to a **subgroup** of $ {\rm Aut}(F(G))$. Am I right? I know this. It can be proved by $N/C$ theorem. I write that in my original post. It’s not exactly where I got stuck. I noticed there was a typo and it might have made you think I think that map is surjective. I know $G/F(Z(G))$ is isomorphic to a **subgroup** of ${\rm Aut}(F(G))$ and $F(G)/Z(F(G))\cong {\rm Inn}(F(G))$ and I also know I can apply the third isomorphism theorem to get closer to the conclusion. But I just don’t know what to do next. I wonder if my question is not clear.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Thanks for your kind comments. Actually those pieces were all mentioned in my original post and I’m afraid that they are not what I was asking. It really seems close to the conclusion with those pieces. But I just don’t know how to push forward. It’s quite obvious that $G/F(G)\cong G/Z(F(G)\big/ F(G)/Z(F(G))$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(G)/{\rm Inn}(G)$ since the $G/Z(F(G))$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(G)$ and $F(G)/Z(F(G))\cong {\rm Inn}(G)$. But it’s not sufficient. I think there’s still something missing, I also mentioned that in my post.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson I want to take an example. Please point it out if it doesn’t make sense. Assume that $A$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $B\trianglelefteq A$. Also, assume that $N\trianglelefteq M$. If $A\cong M$ and $B\cong N$, then it is **Not** true in general that $A/B\cong M/N$. So in the case that we were talking about, $G={\rm Aut}(F(G))$, $B={\rm Inn}(F(G))$, $M=G/Z(F(G))$, $N=F/Z(F(G))$, it’s just the same: $M$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $G$, namely $A$, and $N\cong B$. But we don’t have $A/B\cong M/N$ in general. What I was asking was how to prove it in this specific case.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Thanks for your patience. You are very kind. It’s my fault and I will think more about it.

Comment: It is not a question of "fault", but you do probably have to figure it out for yourself.

Comment: Posted nigh-simulatenously in math.stackexchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3655320/why-g-fg-is-isomorphic-to-a-subgroup-of-mathrmoutfg

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thanks. I was about to delete this post but there was an answer then so I wasn’t able to delete it. Now I know that one should not post the same questions both on MO and MSE, sorry for that. I just thought MO and MSE are not the same site, and many contributors don’t visit both MO and MSE, so I asked a couple of questions that I thought suitable for both sites. I’ve deleted all that kind of posts if I’m able to. You mentioned that I’ve been a user for more that two years. Yes, but actually I had not been using this site for about one and half years before the beginning of 2020.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Sorry for that. I won’t do that again. And thanks for your contribution to both sites!

Comment: @Hello: I understand you are not able to delete the question. Nonetheless, it was important to indicate the cross post with links to prevent duplication of efforts.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson When I went through the proof, I found we actually don’t need to use the third isomorphism theorem: Because $F(G)$ is normal in $G$, there’s a homomorphism $\phi:G\to {\rm Aut}(F(G))$ whose kernel is $C_G(F(G))=Z(F(G))\subseteq F(G)$. We have $G/F(G)\mathbf{\cong \phi(G)/\phi(F(G))=}\phi(G)/{\rm Inn}(F(G))\le {\rm Aut}(F(G))/{\rm Inn}(F(G))$. So although the isomorphism theorem actually fails to help, the real key part is $G/F(G)\cong \phi(G)/\phi(F(G))$ which is actually linked to the first isomorphism theorem. Please tell me if my argument does not make sense. Thanks.

Comment: That's what I explained (or tried to) in the comments before. These are now deleted. It's indeed true that the third isomorphism theorem isn't really necessary.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Yes, I was confused by use of the third isomorphism there. What we need to apply here is actually the first isomorphism theorem. Thanks! I’ll write an answer and make it clear that the third isomorphism theorem here is not really necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For (2), there is a general construction at work here. Given a short exact sequence of groups

$$1 \to K \to G \to Q \to 1$$

there is always a well-defined homomorphism $\varphi: Q\to \mathrm{Out}(K)$. The idea is to lift elements of $Q$ into $G$, and have them act on $K$ by conjugation. It would be instructive to work out the specifics yourself! Note that $\ker(\varphi)$ is the image of $C_G(K)$ into $Q$.

---

So, let’s think about the specific situation we’re in. We have a short exact sequence

$$1\to F(G) \to G \to G/F(G) \to 1$$

and a map $\varphi: G/F(G)\to\mathrm{Out}(F(G))$. We want to prove this map is injective. Fortunately, the kernel is the image of $C_G(F(G))$ into $G/F(G)$ ... which we know is trivial since $G$ is solvable! (You mentioned $C_G(F(G)) = Z(F(G)) \subseteq F(G)$ so it collapses in the quotient).

Thus, the kernel is trivial and so $G/F(G)$ naturally sits as a subgroup of $\mathrm{Out}(F(G))$.

Comment: I should note that this general construction comes up often in very natural situations. At least, it does with groups I care about in geometry and topology.